# Worksheet.get_Range method using incorrect date format

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I am trying to read all cell values(dates) from a .CSV file in a range using the Worksheet.get_Range method.

The values(dates) within the cells are being converted in DateTime objects which can be found within range.Value. Unfortunately the converted dates and months are being switched. It is obviously assuming on US date/time formatting rather than UK.

How can I get the these dates to be interpreted using the UK format of 'dd/mm/yy'?

So far I have tried this (although had no luck).

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
```

Here is how I am using the get_range method

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = null;
Workbooks workBooks = null;
Workbook workBook = null;
Worksheet workSheet = new Worksheet();

excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

workBooks = excelApp.Workbooks;
workBook = workBooks.Open(filePath, AddToMru: false);
workSheet = workBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

int activeRowCount = workSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;

string startCell = row + "1";
string endCell = row + activeRowCount.ToString();

Range xlRng = workSheet.get_Range(startCell, endCell)
```

Comment: Could you please show us the entire code snippet causing the problem? As a quick fix, try something like: Range("A1").EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY"; Best regards,

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alex. I have added my code above. Your suggestion unfortunately didn't do the trick. If you have any other ideas, please let me know.